# Prove $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous using sequential criterion

Tags: real-analysis

Stumped. Here is the sequential criterion for absence of uniform continuity:

A function $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ fails to be uniformly continuous if and only if there exists a particular $\epsilon_0>0$ and two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $A$ satisfying $|x_n - y_n|\rightarrow 0$ but $f(x_n) - f(y_n) \geq \epsilon_0$.

I believe the game plan is to find two sequences who both converge to the same value, and show that their squares do not. I'm struggling with this.

Comment: That game plan won't work for any continuous function.  If $x_n\to L$ then $f(x_n)\to L^2$.

Comment: Hmm, then where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: you have to take two functions that do not converge.

Comment: @user3724404: The terms of the sequences get close to each other, but they go off to infinity together, because that is where $f$ takes close $x$ values farther apart.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume the domain of discourse here is ${\bf{R}}$. Choose $x_{n}=n$ and $y_{n}=n+1/n$, then $f(x_{n})-f(y_{n})=n^{2}-(n+1/n)^{2}=-2-1/n^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

how about $(x_n)=\sqrt{n+1}$ and $(y_n)=\sqrt{n}$?